# Eureka: Two Server - One goes down

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix

I have a total of 2 Eureka servers. In the dashboard, the other one is also shown to me as an available replica. The registered services are also visible in both Eureka servers and are updated accordingly.
If one Eureka server crashes/goes down, the registration/deregistration of the services should be done directly in the other Eureka server, right? But this is not the case for me. If I shut down Eureka server 1, the restarted incances are no longer displayed in Eureka server 2 (or deregistered services are no longer taken out).

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    appname: eureka-cluster
    hostname: peer1
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 90
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: true
    expected-client-renewal-interval-seconds: 30
    renewal-percent-threshold: 0.85
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer2:8762/eureka
```

```
server:
  port: 8762

eureka:
  instance:
    appname: eureka-cluster
    hostname: peer2
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 90
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: true
    expected-client-renewal-interval-seconds: 30
    renewal-percent-threshold: 0.85
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer1:8761/eureka
```

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service

server:
  port: 8000

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      deaufaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:{http://peer1:8761/eureka}, ${EUREKA_URI:{http://peer2:8762/eureka}
  instance:
    hostname: service
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 30
```